# Can i get the timestamp for the time only?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

How i get the timestamp for time only or this is not possible to do?

```js
h = now.getHours();
  m = now.getMinutes();
  if(h < 10)
   h = '0' + h;
  if(m < 10)
   m = '0' + m;
var timestring = h + ":" + m;
console.log(now.getTime())); //getTime is get the timestamp consist of date.
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want; what do you expect a timestamp value for just the time to look like?

Comment: Your code works, just make "now" a new Date instance (`var now = new Date()`) and try logging `timestring` to the console, not `now.getTime()`

Comment: I just the timestamp value for time

Comment: the common timestamp include date and time

Comment: Looks like you're refering to the generic meaning of [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) which is likely to confuse lots  of readers that'll assume you're refering to an [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (number of seconds since the unix epoch). If I'm correct, Nicolas' suggestion and Chatastropher's answer seem on point.

Comment: For example :  this timestamp value 1520876491026 include date and time. So it is able to generate the timestamp just for time ?

Comment: Ok, so you're actually talking about the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch. It doesn't really represent the time and date ; it represents a duration (since a fixed point in time, from which you can derive a time and date). However, you could instead calculate the number of milliseconds since the beginning of the day, or if you prefer calculate the timestamp of today's 00:00 and substract it from the timestamp of now ; both methods would produce the same result, which would be the duration between the start of a day and your target time.

Comment: so can i calculate the duration of two time by using number of millisecond ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the number of milliseconds since the start of the day as follows :

```
var date = new Date();
var timeOfTheDayStamp = ((date.getHours() * 60 + date.getMinutes()) * 60 + date.getSeconds()) * 1000 + date.getMilliseconds();
```

Or by substracting the timestamp of the beginning of the day from the current timestamp :

```
var date = new Date();
var startOfTheDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
var timeOfTheDayStamp = date.getTime() - startOfTheDay.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"timestamp for time only"*.

A timestamp is the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (which is **January 1st 1970, at midnight in UTC**). This number is absolute, in the sense that everywhere in the world, anyone would have the same value.

Example: the value you mention in the comments (1520876491026) represents the instant (the exact point in time) equivalent to 1520876491026 milliseconds since the unix epoch.

This value is the same anywhere on Earth. But it corresponds to a different local date and time, depending on the timezone you are. So it can be:

- March 12th 2018 at 17:41:31.026 in UTC
- March 12th 2018 at 14:41:31.026 in Rio de Janeiro (Brazil)
- March **13th** 2018 at 02:41:31.026 in Tokyo

If you want the time of the day (hour, minute, second, millisecond), you must convert the timestamp to a timezone (which one? it's up to you).